# Binding Information to the GridView from SQLServer won't work in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, gridview, dataset

I have a form where I upload documents to Gridview and then save to the database.
When I want to load the form, I can't get the document info loaded to my GridView. I have put even an AlertMessage to know if it reads the files and it does. So I get the Message "Table is not empty" when loading the file. I don't know what else, I have to do in order to load the info to the grid. 
Please, help me with it. Here is my code:

```
  <asp:GridView ID="gvUploadDocumentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                   BackColor="White" BorderColor="#CCCCCC" BorderStyle="None" 
                   BorderWidth="1px" CellPadding="4" EmptyDataText="No files uploaded" 
                   ForeColor="Black" GridLines="Horizontal" style="text-align: center;
                   margin:0px auto;" Width="800px">
          <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Filename" HeaderText="File Name" />  
                <asp:TemplateField>
                      <ItemTemplate>
                              <asp:LinkButton ID="lnkDelete" runat="server" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("ID") %>' Text="Delete" OnClick="DeleteFile" />
                      </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
          </Columns>
                <FooterStyle BackColor="#CCCC99" ForeColor="Black" />
                <HeaderStyle BackColor="#333333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <PagerStyle BackColor="White" ForeColor="Black" HorizontalAlign="Right" />
                <SelectedRowStyle BackColor="#CC3333" Font-Bold="True" ForeColor="White" />
                <SortedAscendingCellStyle BackColor="#F7F7F7" />
                <SortedAscendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#4B4B4B" />
                <SortedDescendingCellStyle BackColor="#E5E5E5" />
                <SortedDescendingHeaderStyle BackColor="#242121" />
  </asp:GridView>

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         if(!page.IsPostBack)
         {
             LoadRequestInfo();
             LoadDocuments();
         }
    }

    public void LoadDocuments()
    {
        CommonCollection c = new CommonCollection();
        var CTS = c.COMPTRACKERCONNECTIONSTRING();
        var CTS_conn = new SqlConnection(CTS.ConnectionString);
        try
        {
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("CTS_GetDocuments", CTS_conn);
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
            cmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RequestId", "1F0C0732-34CD-48DC-9730-268FE17BAF03"));
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            CTS_conn.Open();
            da.Fill(ds);
            CTS_conn.Close();

            if (ds != null && ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                gvUploadDocumentList.DataSource = ds;
                gvUploadDocumentList.DataBind();
                ShowAlertMessage("Table is not empty");
            }
            else
                ShowAlertMessage("No Data");
         }
         catch (Exception ex)
         {
              ShowAlertMessage(ex.Message.ToString());
         }
    }
```

Comment: Did you forget a tag or two?  SQL is a query language.  That's it.  What about C#?  Your DB technology? (is it SQL server?  Oracle?)

Comment: I had added the tags during the submission, but not sure why it didn't take them. I have added them again.

Comment: Please put `catch` block as well. High chances that an exception is being thrown and you are just ignoring it.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot I have added the catch block but I won't get any error. It reads through the if statement but doesn't load info.

Comment: Instead of `ShowAlertMessage` can you add a label to the page and put messages on that? Maybe `ShowAlertMessage` has some issue.

Comment: @TheVillageIdiot the AlertMessage has no problem. I have added there to just make sure if my storeprocedure gets data. Basically, it runs through the if statement and sets the DataSource to ds and Binds the Data. But I'm not sure why it won't show the result in the Grid.

Comment: Any chance that the column names do not match or some other error on client side console?

Answer (score 0):

Just based on what you are listing, I don't see any code that calls the LoadDocuments() method. If this isn't called in the PageLoad() method, and there is no button or other even that calls it, you will never get the data into your gridview.

An easy way to verify if this is happening is to put a break into your code at the beginning of the method and if VS doesn't start stepping through your code, that's your issue.

Comment: Obviously, I called the loaDocument() method in my pageload function. just didn't post it here. I have added that part now. But that's not the problem. It reads the method, just I don't know why it doesn't load the data to the grid.